# Как сделать подсказку в Entry и открытие нового окна на координатах предыдущего?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Надо сделать подсказку в поле ввода(как на скрине) в Tkinter, а также открытие нового окна на месте предыдущего. То есть если мы нажимаем кнопку, то открывается новое окно по координатам, на которых было предыдущее окно. Возможно ли такое сделать?

---

Вот скрин:

[image]

Comment: потеряли скрин. И что должно произойти со старым окном: оно закрывается или остается ?

Comment: У меня скрин есть. Он просто с этого сайта, потому сливается. Старое окно закрывается.

Comment: В скрине показано что именно я хочу сделать

Comment: Не задавайте два вопроса в одном.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код класса взял отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47928390/12788763

```
from tkinter import *

class EntryWithPlaceholder(Entry):
    def __init__(self, master=None, placeholder="PLACEHOLDER", color='grey'):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.placeholder = placeholder
        self.placeholder_color = color
        self.default_fg_color = self['fg']

        self.bind("<FocusIn>", self.focus_in)
        self.bind("<FocusOut>", self.focus_out)

        self.put_placeholder()

    def put_placeholder(self):
        self.insert(0, self.placeholder)
        self['fg'] = self.placeholder_color

    def focus_in(self, *args):
        if self['fg'] == self.placeholder_color:
            self.delete('0', 'end')
            self['fg'] = self.default_fg_color

    def focus_out(self, *args):
        if not self.get(): self.put_placeholder()

def open_window(ui):
    geo = ui.geometry().split('+')
    x=geo[-2]; y=geo[-1]
    ui.destroy()
    root=Tk()
    root.geometry(f'300x300+{x}+{y}')
    root.mainloop()

ui = Tk()
x=50
y=50
ui.geometry(f'200x200+{x}+{y}')
e1 = EntryWithPlaceholder(ui)
e1.insert(0, 'placeholder example')
e1.bind('<FocusIn>', lambda args: e1.delete(0, 'end'))
e1.grid(row=0, column=0)

btn1 = Button(ui, text='Новое окно', width=10, height=10, command= lambda : open_window(ui))
btn1.grid(row=1, column=0)

ui.mainloop()
```